# Making SSL Connection using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio

Basically a have the code to make an http call to server and handle the response but I want to secure the data travelling and make the call https.

For that I have this executor.hpp

```
class Executor
{
public :
  Executor(Cli &cli):ssock(svc)
  {
      //! Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(cli.getIP(), "8080");
    endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
  }

  int connect();
  int write(RequestCreator &requestcreator);

boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> &getSocket() { return    ssock; }

private :

boost::asio::io_service svc;
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(svc, ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssock(svc, ctx);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator;

};
```

and this executor.cpp

```
int Executor::connect()
{
  boost::system::error_code ec ;
  boost::asio::connect(ssock.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator );
  ssock.handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::handshake_type::client);

  if (ec)
  {
    ssock.lowest_layer().close();
    svc.stop();
    return 0;
  }
  return 1;
 }

 int Executor::write(RequestCreator &requestCreator)
 {
   boost::system::error_code ec ;
   boost::asio::write(ssock, requestCreator.getRequest(), ec);
   if (ec)
   {
     ssock.lowest_layer().close();
     svc.stop();
     return 0;
   }
  return 1;
}
```

and below is the full error on compiler

```
c:\cygwin64\home\admin\sandbox\webcli\executor.hpp(30) : error C2061:   syntax error : identifier 'svc'
c:\cygwin64\home\admin\sandbox\webcli\executor.hpp(31) : error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'svc'
c:\cygwin64\home\admin\sandbox\webcli\executor.hpp(15) : error C2436: 'ssock' : member function or nested class in constructor initializer list
c:\cygwin64\home\admin\sandbox\webcli\executor.hpp(25) : error C3867: 'Executor::ssock': function call missing argument list; use '&Executor::ssock' to create a pointer to member
c:\cygwin64\home\admin\sandbox\webcli\executor.hpp(25) : error C2440:  'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<Stream> (__cdecl   Executor::* )(void)' to 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<Stream> &'
    with
    [
        Stream=boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket
    ]
```

Comment: You... didn't ask a question.

Comment: I see the edit. Let's read

Comment: Okay, I've read it. The question is untreatable. None of the code makes sense and the error doesn't relate to the "code" at all. See my answer.

Comment: Rather than dumping code, please consider taking the extra time and effort to provide a cleanly formatted [mcve].  It can help make everyones time more productive, and may even help you solve it on your own in the process.  For example, [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7335f894bd19dedb) is a MCVE based on the code in question.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind now on wards, thanks ! @TannerSansbury but can you tell whats wrong with the code ? I mean the errors

Answer (score 2):

1. The error message refers to a class `Executor` which isn't in your code. Are you compiling the right thing?
2. `boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(svc, ssl::context::method::sslv23_client);`

   this should not compile, unless `svc` is also a type in your code. Use braces.
3. `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssock(svc, ctx);`

   This will most definitely not compile then. Same problem.
4. `Connect(Data &data) : socket(ioService) {`

   - Socket is not declared. What is it? (Assuming you might have meant `ssock`).
   - `ioService` is not declared. What is it? (Assuming you might have meant `svc`).
5. Contrast

   ```
    int Connect::write(CreatRequest &requestCreator) {
   ```

   with

   ```
    int write(RequestCreator &requestcreator);
   ```

   Which is it? Compilers are not going to guess what you mean. If you mean `RequestCreator` you're gonna have to type that, and not `CreatRequest`.

All in all, there's no real question, just a lot of blindly copied/paste "code-like" text.

Fixing all the above in the most straightforward way possible:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4294ff5de656eca)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>

struct Data {
    std::string getIP() const { return "localhost"; }
};


class Connect {
  public:
    Connect(Data &data) {
        //! Get a list of endpoints corresponding to the server name.
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(svc);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(data.getIP(), "8080");
        endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    }

    int connectServer();
    struct RequestCreator {
        auto getRequest() const { return boost::asio::buffer("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"); }
    };
    int write(RequestCreator &requestcreator);

    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> &getSocket() { return ssock; }

  private:
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    boost::asio::ssl::context ctx{svc, boost::asio::ssl::context::method::sslv23_client};
    boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> ssock{svc, ctx};
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator;
};

int Connect::connectServer() {
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    boost::asio::connect(ssock.lowest_layer(), endpoint_iterator);
    if (ec) {
        ssock.lowest_layer().close();
        svc.stop();
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int Connect::write(RequestCreator &requestCreator) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    boost::asio::write(ssock, requestCreator.getRequest(), ec);
    if (ec) {
        ssock.lowest_layer().close();
        svc.stop();
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

main() {
    Data data;
    Connect c(data);
}
```

Comment: Actually the class name is executor i have changed it to post the question to Connect @sehe

Comment: okay let's make it straight and easy for you to understand and relate with the problem, i am editing the question and this time with full stack of  errors and code

Comment: The edit basically fixes some of the issues in the way my answer already did. The answer is unchanged. My resulting code worked all along as you could see [live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4294ff5de656eca) all along.

Comment: That's working well, but i guess i have to go deep in what my dev environment is providing me !

Comment: How things are compiling on your environment ! I am still getting errors as follows                                                                                                              executor.hpp(30) : error C2473: 'ctx' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list.
executor.hpp(30) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
executor.hpp(30) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
executor.hpp(30) : error C2602: 'sslv23_client' is not a member of a base class of 'Executor'

Comment: @sehe how do you return boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> &getSocket() { return ssock; } i tried to return the ssl::stream it give build error error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'boost::asio::ssl::stream<Stream> (__cdecl Executor::* )(void)' to 'const boost::asio::ssl::stream<Stream> &'

Comment: @Milind you have not looked at all my edits carefully enough. I explained why your members parse as function declarations. Use braces, not parentheses for NSMI. My answer had that fix from the very start.